# WAMP Error in starting WAMP icon is orange after replacing SSL certificates

Tags: ssl, openssl, wamp

This is my first time using WAMP I had to remove expired certificates from  WAMP I just replaced my certificates in ssl certificate folder, I replaced my privatekey with the privatekey From primary domain webserver(GoDaddy Apache) and tried to restart the WAMP services It does not restart anymore.

The error That is present in Event Viewer is

***The wampapache service terminated with service-specific error Incorrect function..***

This must be a noob question. But what can I do to install the new certificates(Please note the WAMP server is serving my subdomain).

What am I missing?Help would be appreciated very much.

Comment: It sould be 100 things. You dont give us much information. Did it work before the certificates expired?

Comment: Yes it did...the certificates were working fine before they expired. I just created a folder for the certificates placed my new certificates in them and changed the ssl-config file... Should I be doing anything else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was in the config file. The previous team messed up naming files in them.